# Mysql: how to reuse a calculation within a query

Tags: mysql, syntax, label

I have a query below that I use to retrieve the records not updated for a given time (in hours) and order it by elapsed time:

```
SELECT TABLE.Key, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, TABLE.Date_last_consulted, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP)
FROM TABLE WHERE TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, TABLE.Date_last_consulted,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) <= 7 ORDER BY TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, TABLE.Date_last_consulted,
CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

As you can see, it calls multiple times TIMESTAMPDIFF, which is not very efficient as all these calls lead to useless SQL calculations.

I was wondering if there were a way to reuse the calculations so it is processed only once?

Thanks a lot for your help.

Florent

Comment: I hope you don't mind that I edited your question, I think it will get more attention with this title and body text. Best regards

Comment: Not at all, thanks a lot for spending time to rewrite it. My english is not very good :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT 
    t.Key, t.dif
FROM (
        SELECT key, TIMESTAMPDIFF(HOUR, TABLE.Date_last_consulted, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP) dif
        FROM TABLE
     ) t
WHERE 
    t.dif <= 7 
ORDER BY 
    t.dif
```

Comment: Sure, I will be able to test it tomorrow. The structure of the request you used is very interessting, I will look at it at the documentation in order to understand. Thanks a lot. Best Regards.

Comment: In fact I have been able to test it and it worked like a charm. Tanks a lot Sebas, I will remember how to "name" a sub query and access its result, this is very helpfull. Best Regards.